# Snap to full screen not working (dual monitors)

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors

I just updated to 12.04 and I have found a highly annoying bug, I am wondernig if there is a work around.  The snap feature, where you drag a window to the top of the screen and it will then fill the screen always moves that window the the main display when using any none-native app.

What I mean by that, any app besides terminal or the file browser will get moved to the main display. (so web browswer, my ftp client)

Anyone know a fix?

Edit: Its not just the snap but the full screen button on the top left corner of the window does the same thing. This is highly annoying!

Comment: I have this problem as well - are your screens different resolutions? The best place to deal with bugs in Ubuntu is http://launchpad.net - the Ubuntu software project tracker, where you may find a bug report and any discussion related to it including workarounds.

Comment: Yes they are different resolutions (I don't even think they sell 1920x1280 monitors anymore! Would love to get one.)

Comment: That's consistent with my experience this does not happen on my setup at home which has 2 x 1680x1050 displays, but does happen at work where I have  1920x1080 + 1280x1024

Comment: I have the same problem w/ my dual monitor setup with my laptop and an external monitor. Any window I maximize will only go to the external monitor. Really annoying.

Comment: I guess that it has been fixed by the upgrade to:
 xserver-xorg:i386 (7.6+12ubuntu1, 7.6+12ubuntu2) 
 xserver-xorg-video-all:i386 (7.6+12ubuntu1, 7.6+12ubuntu2)
xserver-xorg-input-all:i386 (7.6+12ubuntu1, 7.6+12ubuntu2)
x11-common:i386 (7.6+12ubuntu1, 7.6+12ubuntu2), xorg:i386 (7.6+12ubuntu1, 7.6+12ubuntu2)

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found the issue, if you have different sized monitors and are trying to go full screen on a smaller monitor and the height of the current window is larger than the monitor you are on it will instead maximize on your larger screen. Didn't do this before but 12.04 but it is what it is.

Comment: This is my situation, too.  My main monitor is 1920x1080, and my second monitor is 1440x900.  I can manually resize the window, then it will snap full screen in the second monitor, but that's not the solution I want.  I want to be able to drag from bigger to smaller seamlessly.