# Dual Monitor Maximize Problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, screen, monitor, maximized

I have a laptop with an external monitor attached. However everything maximizes to the external monitor, no matter how or where I maximize the windows. I want to be able to have windows maximized in the monitor it is currently in.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information?  For instance, what video drivers are you using? (e.g. the proprietary Nvidia drivers do not fully implement the same interfaces as the free drivers)  Are you running in mirror mode (i.e. the two screens showing the same content), or is the desktop spanned over the two screens?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to [resize the window before maximizing](https://askubuntu.com/a/131298/69881).